# How to fix results of changing directory name to lowercase/uppercase?

Tags: tfs

Problem: long ago a directory in TFS was changed from `foo` to `Foo`. As result over the time this directory accumulated a lot of files and subdirs with `Server Name` (as displayed by `Advanced/Properties...` context menu) that look like `$/.../foo/...` or `$/.../Foo/...`.

On Windows it causes no problems. But on Linux `Get Source` step of related build definition ends up creating separate dirs (`Foo` and `foo`) breaking the build.

Version: TFS 2018 Update 2

Questions:

1. Why renaming folder in TFS didn't change `Server Name`s recursively? How to fix that?
2. Is there a way to "go back in time" and fix this issue retroactively (to be able to build old versions)?
3. Is there an option that forces `Get Source` step to ignore case on Linux or smth to that effect?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of those things that you're going to bump into dealing with one platform that has case sensitivity and one that doesn't.

My recommendation is to put a build step in place that runs a shell script that copies from 'foo' to 'Foo'. It's ugly, but it will solve the problem.

To answer the specific questions:

1. Not sure what you mean.
2. No.
3. No.

Comment: Q1 I renamed a folder in TFS (from `foo` to `Foo`) it is expected that TFS will apply this change recursively to `Server Name` of every sub-element (file/dir) of that directory. How TFS ended up with a mix of old and new names?

Comment: Also, apparently there is [a setting (see 'case enforcement')](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/concepts/repository-settings?view=vsts) that can help with these issues. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to go back and change/fix history...

Comment: @C.M. That's for Git repos, not TFVC. If you're talking about a Git repo, then that's fine -- you can rewrite your repo's history to fix the issue. If you're talking about TFVC, you can't rewrite TFVC history.

Comment: Huh... I missed that part :-\ Any insight on Q1 or it is still unclear what I meant?

Comment: @C.M. Tested and the folder name changed, also reflected in `Server Name` and the Get sources step in agent. You can try to enable `Clean`  option in `Get sources` step, then check it again. (Clean to `True` and select `Sources` in Clean options)

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Well, I suspect subsequent checkins somehow ended up using lower case. Maybe it happened long ago when we used TFS 2015 or older version.

Answer (score 0):

in bash, you can change the variable name from foo to Foo like this:

```
$ a=foo; echo ${a^}
Foo
```

For your questions, there is very little information you have provided for anyone to understand what you are actually looking for.